# DrawBorder doesn't work when passing a custom rectangle to it

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I can't seem to make `DrawBorder` to work when passing a new rectangle object to it:

```
private void answered_choice_1_paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Size s = new Size(Math.Max(answered_choice_1.Height, icon_correct.Height) + 4,  answered_choice_1.Width + 22 + this.default_margin + 4);
    Point p = new Point(answered_choice_1.Location.X - 22 - this.default_margin - 2, answered_choice_1.Location.Y - 2);
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(p, s);
    if (icon_correct.Location.Y == answered_choice_1.Location.Y)
    {
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, r, Color.Green, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
    }
}
```

However, passing a label's rectangle works:

```
private void answered_choice_1_paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (icon_correct.Location.Y == answered_choice_1.Location.Y)
    {
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, answered_choice_1.DisplayRectangle, Color.Green, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
    }
}
```

As you can see from the code, my intent is to draw a rectangular border around the `answered_choice_1` label and `icon_correct` pictureBox, so the second code excerpt does draw a rectangle but I want to draw the rectangle from the first excerpt.

**Edit:**
I've narrowed it down to this:

```
int x,y;
x = answered_choice_1.Location.X - 22 - this.default_margin - 2;
y = answered_choice_1.Location.Y - 2;
Point p = new Point(x, y);
```

Using the debugger I've found out that `answered_choice_1.Location.Y - 2` evaluates to `210` buy `y` gets the value `0`; This is very strange but consistent: if I call a different constructor for the Rectangle `r`, I get the same outcome.

Any further help would be appreciated.

**Second Edit** The edit before was wrong, although that's the data that I saw in the Visual Studio IDE. Humberto's comment gave me the final clue to what was going on, and I've approved his answer.

Comment: Please use the supported syntax to format code rather than `<pre>` tags. Simply indent each line by 4 spaces, or select the entire block and click the `{}` button on the toolbar.

Comment: Also, where in that code do you call `DrawRectangle`?

Comment: Place a breakpoint over the call to ControlPaint.DrawBorder. Which are the values for r.X, r.Y, r.Width and r.Height? Are you sure they represent valid location and dimensions?

Comment: @Cody Gray thanks, I wrote `DrawRectangle` instead of `DrawBorder` in the title. Fixed now

Comment: @Humberto I've used a MessageBox to print the values: 22 183 20 473

Comment: Both the size and the location of the rectangle are wrong.  The size is wider then the control width (answered_choice_1.Width + 22 + ..).  The location is wrong since it uses Location.X and Location.Y, the client area coordinates start at (0, 0).  Hard to guess what was intended and what the relevance of 22 might be.

Comment: Are these coordinates inside the painting region defined for e.Graphics? If not, the border may be clipped, or invisible at all.

Comment: It's not possible for `y` NOT to be 210 in your edit.  Something else is going on in your code.

Comment: @Humberto how do I find out what's the painting region defined for e.Graphics? I'm not allowed to paint outside the label control? Is there an alternative to paint a border around a picturebox and a label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to paint a border around a pair of controls: an icon aligned to the left of a label. Is this the case?

```
+------------------------------+
|                              |
| ICON   answered_choice_1     |---> border on a 4px margin around both controls
|                              |
+------------------------------+
^        ^
|  22px  |
```

If so, your painting code has a problem. It's trying to use the "surface" (Graphics instance) of `answered_choice_1` to paint *outside* its area. It won't work.

Instead, you can place the icon and the label inside a Panel, then paint the panel's border whenever you need. Somewhat like you already did, but referring to `panel_1` instead of `answered_choice_1`:

```
private void panel_1_paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (icon_correct.Location.Y == answered_choice_1.Location.Y)
    {
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, panel_1.DisplayRectangle,  Color.Green, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can assign a FixedSingle border style to the panel, but AFAIK the border color will be system defined.

Answer (score 2):

Your "size" calculation looks like it is doing height for width, and width for height:

```
Size s = new Size(Math.Max(answered_choice_1.Height, icon_correct.Height) + 4,
                  answered_choice_1.Width + 22 + this.default_margin + 4);
```

Since it's hard to tell what the rest of the code looks like, I can only guess that reversing it might work:

```
Size s = new Size(answered_choice_1.Width + 22 + this.default_margin + 4,
                  Math.Max(answered_choice_1.Height, icon_correct.Height) + 4)
```

Comment: well spotted! they were reversed but this still doesn't show up anything

Comment: @altvali As Hans commented, look at your Point formula.  This should really be handled in the debugger.  What values are you expecting versus what values are you getting.